# Examining continuity and differentiability of function

Tags: calculus

Let
$$
F(x,y) = \begin{cases} \frac{x³\cos(1/y) + y³\cos(1/x)}{(x²+y²)} & \text{for $x,y ≠ (0,0)$} \\
         0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$

How to examine the continuity at $(0,0)$

Comment: $x,y\ne (0,0)$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm sure he means $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$.

Comment: What is $F(1,0)$ then?

Answer (score 1):

How to examine continuity at $(0,0)$?

A function $f$ is continuous at $(a,b)$ if 
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (a,b)}f(x,y)=f(a,b)
$$
just compute the limit.

Hint for limit: Convert to polar coordinates and express limit as $r*(\text{a bunch of bounded stuff})$

Comment: can you help me with calculating the limit?

Comment: @YashwanthKasturi I added a hint. Let me know if this helps

Comment: No buddy... im getting stuck in between... i took x=r cosa; y = r sina.. but i am not able to eliminate indeterminate form from limit

Comment: @qbert  Actually , I had a related question. Is it possible without graph to check whether a given function is continuous in its entire domain . There are infinite points and checking continuity at end points can't give the answer

Comment: Sure. If you can show continuity for any arbitrary point in the domain, then you have shown continuity of the function everywhere. Try with $f(x)=x^2$.

Comment: @qbert  but to check continuity , I will need to calculate the limit , and that too at a point like 0, 1 etc. Do you mean using epsilon delta method when using an  arbitrary point?

Comment: Yes exactly, use epsilon delta for some point a

Answer (score 0):

Let $x = r \cos\theta$ and $y = r \sin \theta$. Of course, $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Rewrite $F(x,y)$ as $F(r,\theta)$, that is for $r>0$:

$F(r,\theta) = \frac{r^3\cos^3\theta\cos{(1/r\sin \theta)+r^3 \sin^3\theta\cos(1/r\cos \theta)}}{r} \\= r^2\cos^3\theta\cos{(1/r\sin \theta)+r^2 \sin^3\theta\cos(1/r\cos \theta)}.$

Then, consider a delta-epsilon proof noting that

$\mid F(r,\theta)\mid \;\leq \; \mid r^2\cos^3\theta\cos{(1/r\sin \theta)} \mid + \mid r^2 \sin^3\theta\cos(1/r\cos \theta) \mid \; \leq \;2r^2 $

(where the first inequality comes from the triangle inequality).

Comment: But what about limit value..is it 2r2

Comment: What happens to $2r^2$ as $r$ goes to $0$?

Comment: It's approaches 0

Comment: That's basically the entire proof. For all $\theta$, as $r$ goes to zero we have that the function goes to $0$. Is something still troubling you about the problem? As a note: this only works because we don't require $\theta$ to be fixed, hence the function value approaches 0 independent of the path taken.